# mysql logic to update some records

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a specific recordset of 48 records (1 day over 1/2 hour slots).

I want to reduce the value of `l` of the top 24 records (top by `l` field `DESC`) by a pre-known amount and all i have is the date and the amount I want to reduce by (a php var called $int).

Currently, I am reducing all 48 records as such:

```
UPDATE r SET l = l - $int WHERE thedate = '$kDate'
```

(updates 48 records)

How do I update the top 24?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `LIMIT 24' to the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE r 
SET l = l - $int 
WHERE thedate = '$kDate'
order by l desc
limit 24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE r SET l = l - $int WHERE thedate = '$kDate'
ORDER BY l DESC
LIMIT 24
```

Comment: ah, was it that easy? (feeling embarrassed)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE r SET l = l - $int WHERE thedate = '$kDate' ORDER BY thedate DESC LIMIT 24
```